# Проверить заданные предложения на ключевое слово, которое задает юзер в C (си)

Tags: c, строки

Ввести последовательность предложений и ключевое слово. Определить предложения, которые содержат заданное ключевое слово.

 Пример: 
Введите ключевое слово: **Привет**
Введите строки: **Как дела? Привет мир. Си ван лав. Передавай привет.**

Вивод:
**Привет мир.

Передвай привет**

Попытался написать сам, но не знаю как вивести всю строку содержащую ключевое слово.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char kword[32], strings[256];
    char i;
    printf("Enter key word:  ");
    gets(kword);
    printf("Enter strings:  ");
    gets(strings);
    char *pch = strtok(strings, " ");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(kword, pch) == 0)
        {
            puts(pch);
        }
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: `strtok()` "портит" исходную строку. Может сделать ее копию, которую и печатайте, если нашли слово

Comment: Вообще деление текста на предложения в общем случае задача отнюдь не тривиальная и требует больших усилий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char kword[32], strings[256];
    int count = 0;
    printf("Enter key word:  ");
    gets_s(kword);
    printf("Enter strings:  ");
    gets_s(strings);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(kword); i++)
        if(isupper(kword[i]))
            kword[i] = tolower(kword[i]);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(strings); i++)
        if (strings[i] == '.' || strings[i] == '!' || strings[i] == '?')
            count++;

    char ** pch = (char **) malloc(100);
    pch[0] = strtok(strings, ".!?");

    int n = 0;
    while (pch[n] != NULL)
    {
        n++;
        pch[n] = strtok(NULL, ".!?");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char * str = (char *)malloc(strlen(pch[i]) + 1);

        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(pch[i]) + 1; j++) {
            str[j] = pch[i][j];
        }

        str[strlen(pch[i])] = '\0';

        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(pch[i]); j++)
            if(isupper(pch[i][j]))
                pch[i][j] = tolower(pch[i][j]);


        char * w = strtok(pch[i], " ,-:");
        while (w != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(kword, w) == 0) {
                printf("%s \n", str);
                break;
            }
            w = strtok(NULL, " ,-:");
        }
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: спасибо, лучший)